# The " access denied " message after I remove bitlocker

Tags: hard-drive, permissions, encryption, bitlocker

So I was trying to encrypt my drive with BitLocker but suddenly my house power went off. After I turned on my pc again my drive gave me an "access denied" error. I didn't know that BitLocker was still working and I thought BitLocker failed to encrypt during that shut down... so I went to setting and turned BitLocker off.  But still, my drive is at that access denied point.

I tried to change the owner at the security tab in the properties but it won't let me do it even as an administrator.
I tried BitLocker and let it finish encrypting the drive. It was completed successfully this time. But after I put in my password it i still get an access denied message.

I am frustrated right now and I need my files. If you have any solution for this I would be really appreciated it.
Wish you the best...
[Screenshots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TpkdO.jpg)

Comment: There really isn't a solution to this problem.  You allowed the process to finish, but have you reenabled BitLocker protection, I assume this wasn't a system drive since you were able to get back into Windows?  You should [edit] your question instead of submitting a comment.  The access denied message, is it a permission error, or a BItLocker authentication error?

Comment: Thanks for the respond.  This is not system drive. My c drive is ok and windows 11 works fine. Its my d drive. This is looks like a permission error since I remove bitlocker and drive is decrypted but still it says access denied.

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot fo the properties of one of the files you don't have access to?

Comment: I added some pictures

Comment: I have bad news. The files are gone.

Comment: I'm thinking about trying to format the drive and try a recovery software on it. Thank you for your time. 

Comment: Fair warning the original files were encrypted. File recovery is unlikely for that reason

Comment: Ramhound is correct but I'll go one further: your files are *unrecoverable*, for that reason. Fortunately you made a backup before trying to encrypt a live and apparently important drive/partition so you can just image that back to the drive, right?